# Using built in validation for records created on client

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 application where I'm allowing users to add 1 to many records on the client using javascript templates. It's working fine and using the right naming convention, the model binding is correctly transforming the post data into the desired collection of objects for the action method.

My question is, is there any way to use the built in MVC validation for records added using this approach.  I've added data annotation attributes to my model but because I'm generating the html for each new record on the client I can't use the html helpers that typically make the process work.

Obviously, I can just add the client side validation myself and let the data annotations validate on the server but I'm wondering if there's a way to take advantage of the built in validation stack for this type of approach so I can maintain all my validation logic on the server.

Comment: Server-side validation should work regardless.  Client-side validation requires the proper attributes, though.  You would have to add those yourself.  But server-side validation doesn't have any access to those, so i'm not sure why you're having a problem.  How are you binding your objects?

Comment: I'm not having any problem with the server side validation

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question.  You made it sound like validation wasn't working at all.  Yes, you have to add the validation attributes manually if doing it client-side.

Answer (score 0):

For example：
The View has two form：form1 and form2。

The form1 has two part.

The first part：
There are two textbox and a Create button and a Save button.

The second part：
There are a .

so, when we fill in two textbox and press the Create button, if not pass validation, then show error messages.
if pass validation, then insert values into the  and insert values to the form2.

[HttpPost] Action Create has a parameter List models.

when we press the Save button, will take values of form2 to controller mapping to List models.

Model

```
public class HomeModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(List<HomeModel> models)
    {
        // TODO: Add insert logic here
    }
```

View：

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.HomeModel
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Create";
 }

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "form1" }))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>HomeModel</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Number)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Number)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Number)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Create" id="btnCreate" />
        <input type="button" value="Save" id="btnSave" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
<table id="tb"></table>
}

<div id="FormInfo" style="display: none;">
    <form action="/Home/Create" id="form2" method="post"></form>
</div>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#form1").submit(function () {
                var ErrorLength = $(".field-validation-error").length;
                if (ErrorLength <= 0) {
                    var nameValue = $("#Name").val();
                    var numberValue = $("#Number").val();
                    InsertToForm2(nameValue, numberValue);
                    InsertToTable(nameValue, numberValue);
                }
                return false;
            });

            $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                $("#form2").submit();
            });
        });

        function InsertToForm2(nameValue, numberValue) {
            var inputCount = $("#form2 input").length / 2;
            var combineHTML = "<input type='text' name='models[" + inputCount + "].Name' value='" + nameValue + "' /> ";
            combineHTML += "<input type='text' name='models[" + inputCount + "].Number' value='" + numberValue + "'/> ";
            $("#form2").append(combineHTML);
        }

        function InsertToTable(nameValue, numberValue) {
            var combineHTML = "<tr><td>" + nameValue + "</td><td>" + numberValue + "</td></tr>";
            $("#tb").append(combineHTML);
        }
    </script>
}
```

[Example Download](http://www.mediafire.com/?8mekwbf836c8kk4)